# Подтверждение загрузки в DownloadManager

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Здравствуйте!

Я использую DownloadManager для загрузки файлов в своем приложении, требуется сделать загрузку и прежде чем продолжить работу с файлом нужно убедиться, что он полностью успел загрузиться.

```
final String DOWNLOAD_FILE = "https://s04g.storage.yandex.net/rdisk/585a6604b6bf33cb41214756c8bcb6e042e43997f4dfe17ad59165adb2050bd1/58a9d0b9/jAtpeUabHpPNIw4Mb7j7hAJKqlCebrorxpbrJybHDsliI2I2klqhwIqCdcp1qNlrvPGP6vLE4syFY40S1bo83Q==?uid=21323916&filename=Music.zip&disposition=attachment&hash=&limit=0&content_type=application%2Fx-zip-compressed&fsize=70303471&hid=4700b296603d09c16a00bed3ec6214e4&media_type=compressed&tknv=v2&etag=5ae8af2d8bce2bd03da3ad9975f7c2c8&rtoken=rWu9ENQ02TvG&force_default=yes&ycrid=na-501eb41ae05c5d3357d490381dc2e603-downloader12g&ts=548e52d1ae040&s=b5e129a2d70b5f19cc9ed9a872b340f5bf2bbaae9b7e264f6c0ac855447e6112&bp=/32/8/data-0.20:40030971360:70303471&pb=U2FsdGVkX1-srN3n6Ub2oPEPgx-KI4tr5AxU4rOtz4d3Y_72xPNBaOzzEU88c7tccKKojdcS1N_Mrd1NUe1woyNHjich9dA-OWWfgK5d33U=";
final String Download_ID = "PREF_DOWNLOAD_ID";
SharedPreferences preferenceManager;
DownloadManager downloadManager;
long id;
int stat = 0;

preferenceManager = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

                // проверяем был ли уже загружен файл
                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/";
                File file = new File(path + "LiveWallpapers/123.zip");
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Файл отсутствует");
                    // загружаем файл
                    Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(DOWNLOAD_FILE);
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);

                    // назначаем имя для файла
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("LiveWallpapers", "123.zip");

                    // сохраняем request id
                    SharedPreferences.Editor PrefEdit = preferenceManager.edit();
                    id = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
                    PrefEdit.putLong(Download_ID, id);
                    PrefEdit.apply();
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Файл уже загружен");
                    // файл уже загружен
                    is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.nature1);
                }


                // ждем загрузку файла
                if (is == null) {
                    repeat:
                    for (int z = 0; z < 30; z++) {
                        // проверяем процесс загрузки файла
                        BroadcastReceiver downloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                            @Override
                            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Проверка метки");
                                String action = intent.getAction();
                                if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                                    DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
                                    query.setFilterById(id);
                                    Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(query);
                                    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                                        if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == cursor.getInt(columnIndex)) {
                                            Log.i(TAG, "Метка об окончании загрузки");
                                            stat = 1;
                                            cursor.close();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        };

                        if (stat == 1) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Открываем анимацию");
                            is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.nature1);
                            break;
                        } else {
                            // отправляем проверку на загруженность файла
                            registerReceiver(downloadReceiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
                            try {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Файл в процессе загрузки...");
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            }
                            continue repeat;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

В принципе файл скачивается корретно, если же файл с таким именем уже существует, то этот процесс пропускается.
Проблема заключается в том, что если файла не существует и он загружается я не получаю уведомления об его окончании загрузки, т.е. не срабатывает переход сюда

```
BroadcastReceiver downloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    ...
}
```

По логу вижу что сначала появляется 'Файл отсутствует', потом 'Файл в процессе загрузки...', но даже по завершению загрузки логи продолжают сыпать 'Файл в процессе загрузки...'

Руководствовался вот этой статьей при написании кода:
http://blog.vogella.com/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/

В файле манифеста добавлено:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Некоторые могут сказать, что нужно делать отдельный класс и прослушивать события в нем вот так:

```
public class DownloadBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "log";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
            // ?
        }
    }
}
```

Манифест

```
<receiver android:name=".DownloadBroadcastReceiver"
   android:enabled="true"
   android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Но вот не знаю я как потом это событие передать в свой класс из DownloadBroadcastReceiver, где происходит работа с кодом, а перетащить весь код туда у меня тоже не получится...

---

Сделал вот так:

```
downloadWallpaper("https://media.giphy.com/media/rAJfdmusNFDDG/source.gif", "source.gif");
Uri path =(Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/LiveWallpapers/" + "source.gif"));
Log.i(TAG, "Путь Uri " + path);
is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(path);
```

Но что-то все-равно не нравится ему...

```
02-21 04:43:50.940 2179-2179/com.developer.skyline.livewallpapers I/log: Файл отсутствует по указанному пути /storage/sdcard/LiveWallpapers/source.gif
02-21 04:43:50.970 2179-2179/com.developer.skyline.livewallpapers I/log: Файл в процессе загрузки...
02-21 04:43:51.970 2179-2179/com.developer.skyline.livewallpapers I/log: Файл уже загружен
02-21 04:43:51.970 2179-2179/com.developer.skyline.livewallpapers I/log: Путь Uri /storage/sdcard/LiveWallpapers/source.gif
02-21 04:43:51.970 2179-2179/com.developer.skyline.livewallpapers I/log: Error creating NyanEngine
                                                                         java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /storage/sdcard/LiveWallpapers/source.gif
                                                                             at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1049)
                                                                             at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:904)
                                                                             at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:629)
                                                                             at com.developer.skyline.livewallpapers.LiveWallpaperService$GifEngine.<init>(LiveWallpaperService.java:84)
                                                                             at com.developer.skyline.livewallpapers.LiveWallpaperService.onCreateEngine(LiveWallpaperService.java:40)
                                                                             at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$IWallpaperEngineWrapper.executeMessage(WallpaperService.java:1028)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:40)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `если файла не существует и он загружается` – противоречие тут.

Answer (score 1):

В общем удалось решить данную проблему без всякого прослушивания о завершении загрузки таким вот образом:

```
// скачиваем файл
        public void downloadWallpaper(String url, String name) {

            SharedPreferences preferenceManager = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            String Download_ID = "PREF_DOWNLOAD_ID";

            repeat: for (int z = 0; z < 10; z++) {
                if (is != null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Файл загружен успшно");
                    is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.nature1);
                    break;
                } else {
                    // проверяем был ли уже загружен файл
                    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/";
                    File file = new File(path + "LiveWallpapers/" + name);
                    if (!file.exists()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Файл отсутствует");
                        // загружаем файл
                        Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(url);
                        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);

                        // назначаем имя для файла
                        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("LiveWallpapers", name);

                        // сохраняем request id
                        SharedPreferences.Editor PrefEdit = preferenceManager.edit();
                        long id = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
                        PrefEdit.putLong(Download_ID, id);
                        PrefEdit.apply();
                    } else {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Файл уже загружен");
                        // файл уже загружен
                        is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.nature1);
                        break;
                    }

                    if (is == null) {
                        try {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Файл в процессе загрузки...");
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                        continue repeat;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Осталось разобраться как загруженную картинку запихнуть в InputStream?
В данный момент картинка берется из каталога raw таким вот образом:

```
is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.nature1);
```

Мне же нужно будет брать картинку из каталога

```
File file = new File(path + "LiveWallpapers/" + name);
```

и добавить ее в поток, кто подскажет как это прописать?

Answer (score 0):

Очередной раз отвечу на свой собственный вопрос, проблема была решена таким вот образом:

```
downloadWallpaper("https://media.giphy.com/media/rAJfdmusNFDDG/source.gif", "source.gif");
Uri path =(Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/LiveWallpapers/" + "source.gif"));
is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(path);
```

Как видите для чтения файла необходимо добавить вот этот кусок в начало пути  **file://**

Всем спасибо, все свободны :)